# Execute wp_logout_url('/') in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to do a check with JavaScript then based on condition I want to log the user out. How do I call the PHP from JS? Doing research I find lots on info on how to create a logout link, but I am trying to execute it inside JS instead.

Something like:

```
if(variable == 1) {
   EXECUTE LOGOUT WITH NO CONFIRMATION (in PHP the function to show the link is "<?php echo wp_logout_url('/redirect/url/goes/here') ?>")
} else {                
    DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE;
};
```

Comment: This is not a PHP function its wordpress function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't simply setting `location.href` do the trick,
as the URL would be pre-rendered with PHP?

```
if(  variable == 1  ) {
  window.location.href = '<?php echo wp_logout_url('/redirect/url/') ?>';  
} else {                
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE;
};
```

Comment: assuming of course you're using the JS inline inside a WP template, not in an external JS file...